# How to checkout a forked pull request locally with TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, pull-request, git-checkout

I've slowly learned that most git clients, beyond the classic command-line tool, don't allow the checkout of pull-requests from forked repos for local review before merging.

Nonetheless its difficult to know for sure if a client lacks pull request checkout capability.  So that brings me to TortoiseGit.

Does TortoiseGit support the checkout of pull-requests from other users' forked repos?

How does one do so?

Note: I don't mean the normal branch checkout process or creating a pull request.  I mean checking out a pull request from another user's forked repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TortoiseGit->Fetch. Set `Arbitrary URL` and `Remote Branch`. Their values are expected to be found in the pull request.

TortoiseGit->Switch/Checkout. Set `Branch` with `FETCH_HEAD`. You could create a new branch in the meantime or do it later. If no branch is created, you will be in detached HEAD state.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid setting urls and branches manually, as in the accepted answer, you can choose `TortoiseGit->Pull` and click on the `...` icon after `Remote branch`.

All pull requests will then appear conveniently in a menu, and you can choose the one matching the id, for example on Github, where PR 204 will have a reference of `refs/pull/204/head` and `refs/pull/204/merge` (which you can enter manually as well in that format, if the list is long).

The `merge` version is easiest to use since it is merged with the branch the PR was made against, you can't conveniently access `head` directly. So pull the `merge` version, do the testing, and if everything's fine you can just push it, to merge and close the PR. Otherwise you can add additional commits, or reset the branch to its previous state.